# Python/Ionic/MySQL Notifications

Tags: python, mysql, node.js, express, ionic-framework

I have a code in Python that inserts data into a table in MySQL. What I want to do and I do not know how to do it is to be able to receive the data that is inserted in my application in Ionic. By this I mean to be able to receive only that data that is inserted (not the whole table) to be able to notify in the application, each time a row is inserted in the table.

I tried to do it with observables but I did not understand much about that and it did not work either. The other thing that occurs to me is to use web sockets but I do not know if it will serve me correctly.

If someone can guide me or help, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: it sounds like your in over your head ... but websockets are probably a good place to investigate ... look into `python-websocketserver` I think is a pure python lib thats pretty easy to use

Answer (score 0):

A microservices approach using the Google Cloud Platform might help. Firebase can take care of the real-time updating of your Ionic app via [AngularFire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) with ease. You could host your MySQL database on [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) and, finally, to wire it all together, use Python [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/).

It does, of course, introduce a huge dependency which wouldn't be there had you wired it all up yourself, but there are advantages:

1. It would be quicker to set up than rolling your own websockets etc.
2. Adding advanced functionality like oauth2 becomes really easy
3. The security out-of-the-box will probably be better than what you're able to do yourself

Comment: I chose MySQL because it is a relational database, and Firebase is not. That's why I need to do that interaction with MySQL.